# freuen: with or without "darüber"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

> 1. Ich freue mich, dass du gekommen bist.
> 2. Ich freue mich darüber, dass du gekommen bist.

I've seen both forms used to mean "I'm happy that you've come". Is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, both are fine. The second form may sound a bit more emphasized. So - slightly exaggerated - the first may be uttered when you enter the room, whereas the second may be an answer to "Why do you keep grinning all evening?"